# To what length in the array should I go to calculate correlation function

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

I have a time series data (5000 entries) of a vector quantity. (i.e. 3 components, which are recorded after every fixed time interval of 240 seconds). I want to calculate the Autocorrelation function of this quantity
$\langle \vec{A(t)}\cdot\vec{A(t+\tau)}\rangle $, where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ denotes the process of averaging over whole available array.

The first entry will be average of $ \vec{A_1}\cdot\vec{A_2}+\vec{A_2}\cdot\vec{A_3}+\cdots+A_{4999}\cdot\vec{A_{5000}}$;

The second will be average of  $ \vec{A_1}\cdot\vec{A_3}+\vec{A_2}\cdot\vec{A_4}+\cdots+A_{4998}\cdot\vec{A_{5000}}$;

Third  $ \vec{A_1}\cdot\vec{A_4}+\vec{A_2}\cdot\vec{A_5}+\cdots+A_{4998}\cdot\vec{A_{5000}}$;
and so on.

Doing like this; upto what length of the array should I go. Firstly I was going till the last of the array when I had only two entries; $ \vec{A_1}\cdot\vec{A_4}+A_{2}\cdot\vec{A_{5000}}$ ; but one of my friends told me, that going till the end; my statistics will not make sense. So he advised me to go till specific length say half the array length or 3/4th or something else.
My question is that how to decide what length to choose. Kindly explain.

Comment: Welcome to CV! *Why* do you want to do this calculation?  What purpose would it serve to extend it that far?

Comment: I actually require this in some calculation related to my masters project of modelling the electrmotive force in the solar wind. I have to calculate a coefficient called $\beta$ which is defined by: $\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\overline{\vec{u}(x,t)\cdot\vec{u}(x,t-\tau)}d\tau$; where overline denotes process of ensemble average, which is equal to averaging over time using something called ergodicity principle. To evaluate this expression, first of all the integrand has to be calculated as a time series, which is what I'll obtain by calculating the correlation function.